# Delphi what happens when linking packages?

Tags: delphi, linker, package, delphi-xe3, delphi-10.1-berlin

I've been working on breaking a huge project into small parts, creating a package (dpk) for each part and having the app configured to "Use Runtime Packages". I'm having a issue while linking one of these packages that uses other packages. It's just taking way too long to link.

I was under the impression that when a package (A) requires another package (B), that dependency is only resolved at runtime, but apparently that not the case entirely, because if a remove (B) from the "requires" section of (A), (A) links in a normal amount of time, but otherwise it takes like 30 minutes or more.

So my question is, what exactly happens when Delphi is linking a package that requires another packages?

Comment: Unless you want to use optional plugin modules, using runtime packages will almost certainly make your life much harder.

Comment: You said it like there's another way of braking a Delphi project into parts.

Comment: Why do you want to break it apart. That just creates loads of problems. What is the benefit?

Comment: We use XE3, and as it stands now we can barely build the project. More often than not the IDE crashes or an "out of memory" error is issued. Long ago we decided to break the project into parts, which we called "commonfeature.*", but instead of using dpks, each part is actually a exe that spits the dcus to a common folder we named "_codelink", and from this point on any project that needed something from "commonfeature" would just use the dcu from "_codelink". The problem with that approach is that, we first thought the issue was the compilation part, but as it turns out, it's the linking part.

Comment: So now we decided to convert the "commonfeature" parts from exe to dpk, and that the apps would just use the packages and not have to link all the dcus in "commonfeature".

Comment: I think a far better move would be to switch to a modern version of Delphi which resolves the memory problems, and then you can avoid all the complexity of modularisation. Odd that you tagged this as Berlin when you use XE3.

Comment: We're talking about 8000+ units that would take forever to compile if they were all accessible to the compile. And even if some of it was pre-compiled, assuming we switch to a newer version of Delphi, it'd still take a long time to link the project. I'm under the impression that a project with 8000+ units should be considered a large project and hence modularisation makes sense,

Comment: How many lines of code do you have?

Comment: 4 million+ lines of code.

Comment: Yep, that's a fair whack. About 5 times what I am working with. I can see that the compiler might struggle. Perhaps I don't have the right experience to give you advice.

Comment: I would definitely look into breaking up the application in an exe and a set of DLL's each with a specific task/purpose, optionally COM/ActiveX for interfacing/loading/describing the objects.

Comment: If you still have the source code version around with which you experienced the linking problems, you could download the trial of the current Delphi version (10.1 Berlin Update 2) and test whether the problem still exists. If yes, it might be worth submitting a bug report. If not, it's probably cheaper to update than to invest the time restructuring your project.

Comment: Just to clarify: Our first tests where using XE3, with which there were no problems with the linking of the packages, but some projects, even small ones, would not compile/link due to "out of memory", which is a known bug in XE3's compiler/linker. So we decided to try Berlin, same packages (with small adjustments), and now the problem is the long time it takes to link packages that uses other packages.

Comment: Pehaps the IDE Fix Pack (http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/ide-fix-pack/) might help you. I remember getting something from Andy's site in the past that helped speed up compiling and/or linking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When linking packages, either runtime or design time, all of the dependencies in the linked objects need to be resolved.  The only difference with runtime packages is that they are *loaded* at runtime, so they can ultimately reduce the size of your executable (or suite of executables) where common elements are reused.  The linking behaviour remains the same, however, so if linking is the bottleneck in your build then this will not change if you switch from using DCUs to runtime packages.

If linking *is* the bottleneck in your application then there are some architectural refactoring strategies that you might be able to leverage to streamline the build, but this is a broad topic beyond the scope of this answer.